# Position multiple Divs in center

Tags: css

I have centered 3 divs beside each other in the center, however the one on the right seems to be vertically higher than the other 2 divs. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/or7LL94j/)

```
.x-gallery-center {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.x-gallery-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 370px;
    position: relative;
}
```

What's the culprit?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't post links to external sites. Put all the relevant code and a jsFiddle link demonstrating the issue (when possible) in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, will update my post now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` default alignment is baseline. Add `vertical-align:top` to your `x-gallery-container` class.

```
.x-gallery-container {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
background-color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 370px;
position: relative;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/or7LL94j/2/)

Answer (score 2):

If you make the text in the link in the center shorter it seems to fix the problem, make "Konferencia Rozvoj ľudských zdrojov" -> "Konferencia" and the div's will all appear side-by-side.

Comment: Interesting... I will digg into that to see why it does that. Thanks!